# Apache serving Samba share leads to poor performance?

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, samba, cifs, threads

This is a question about a problematic interaction between Apache and Samba.

Our Linux server (on a private intranet) mounts a Windows share, which is physically thousands of miles away, and serves it via Apache. This lets our users view files on the share via HTTP rather than by file:// URLs. Sometimes, however, a single HTTP hit produces multiple Apache threads all accessing the same SMB file simultaneously for 10 minutes or more in the "Sending Reply" ("W") state. Apache's server-status page shows many identical threads like the following, which is 1434 seconds old, all with slightly different lifetimes (in the "SS" column):

```
Srv     PID     Acc          M   CPU   SS   Req   Conn   Child  Slot     Client         VHost       Request
33-1    28411   0/146/27463  W   9.20  1434 0     0.0    0.56   689.97   192.168.0.25   someserver  GET /share/foo/myfile.xlsx HTTP/1.1
```

Does anybody know why this happens and how we can prevent it? Is there a better way to accomplish our goal of HTTP connections to a Windows share?

Our /etc/fstab entry is:

```
//server//sharename /mnt/foo cifs ro,auto,credentials=/my/file,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

The httpd.conf entry is:

```
Alias /share/foo "/mnt/foo"
<Directory "/mnt/foo">
    EnableSendfile Off
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

We are also seeing load spikes on this server, where load average jumps from normal (1.00) to 20.00 or higher, which might be attributable to this problem.

Thank you very much.